# Как поместить массив с большим количеством элементов в БД MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, arraylist

Есть массив

```
Array(
    0=>(
       Date => "2017-07-08",
       Time => "20:30",
       Nid => "2450"
    ),
1=>(
       Date => "2017-07-09",
       Time => "20:30",
       Nid => "2450"
    ),
2=>(
       Date => "2017-07-10",
       Time => "20:30",
       Nid => "2450"
    ),
3=>(
       Date => "2017-07-11",
       Time => "20:30",
       Nid => "2450"
    ),
.....
N=>(
       Date => "2017-12-31",
       Time => "20:30",
       Nid => "2450"
    )
)
```

В голове всплывает только foreach, но не хотелось бы создавать большое количество обращений к бд, может быть есть какой то универсальный способ как то обработать и вложить в базу послав данные однократно?

В базе так же всего 3 поля соответствующие ключам массива

Извините за кривой код, нет компьютера под рукой))

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (date, time, Nid)
VALUES (1,2,3),
       (2,5,6),
       (7,8,9) .....;` .......... доки https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: А можете на моем примере показать как вложить хотя бы на примере 2 элементов,  ведь у меня не просто (123),(256) а 0->(123), 1->(456)....

Comment: Организуешь цикл, в котором  на каждой итерации получается выражение `( данные1, данные2, данные3)`... все это конкатинируешь через `,` и результирующую строку вставляешь в запрос

Comment: А обратный способ есть?) ну удалить за один определённое количество элементов

Comment: конечно.... читай про `IN` например

Comment: При всем моем уважении, Алексей дал вам очень хреновый совет. Никогда не собирайте SQL-запрос таким образом - это чревато как минимум неочевидными ошибками, а как максимум SQL-инъекцией например. Используйте подготовленный запрос и запускайте его в цикле. БД проглотит их даже не заметив. Что за странная идея экономить на спичках путем переселения в жерло вулкана...

Comment: @rjhdby допустим у меня 5 месяцев и 10 часов которые надо скрыть из примерно 110 дат, тогда 1 час 1 дата, второй час 1 дата и т.д пока не получится около 1100 вариантов, кажется, неужели это мне  с помощью foreach записывать? 1100 запросов, в один момент это уже не спички

Comment: 1100 запросов любая БД съест за доли секунды на самом задрипанном  хостинге. А вот строкой длиной 1100*длина_параметров вполне может и подавиться

Comment: @rjhdby SQL инъекции стоит ожидать если данные от пользователя. В случае если они свои - то не вижу проблем с формированием строки. + разбиение на порции, чтоб БД не давилась)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский про инъекцию же "как максимум". Свои данные тоже далеко не всегда идеальны бывают. Ну и возникает вопрос, занафига строить велосипеды с разбиением на куски, их кусочное склеивание, когда можно одним циклом с prepared пройтись? :)

Comment: @rjhdby хз. по мне так всё от задачи зависит) Собсн, поэтому я не писал ответ)  А велосипед...ну это ж один раз... вон все классы-обертки по работе с БД, по сути, велосипеды)